# Новая пустая строка - удаление Java

Tags: java, текст, filestream

Работаю с текстовым файлом из командной строки. При выполнении команды удаления (remove)строки удаляются, но почему-то добавляется одна пустая строка. Эта появляющаяся пустая строка в дальнейшем, при выполнении команд добавления (add) или просмотра содержимого файла (view) выдает ошибку и делает это все неправильно. Если удалить эту строку "вручную" прямо в файле, - все восстанавливается. Вот код, удаляющий строки:

```
private void removeLine(String lineContent) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    List<String> out = Files.lines(file.toPath())
                            .filter(line -> !line
                            .contains(lineContent))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Files.write(file.toPath(), out, StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
}
```

Если удалить строки, которые расположены в конце файла, то я использую метод:

```
public void eraseLastLine() {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try (RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
        byte b;
        long length = f.length() - 1;
        do {
            length -= 1;
            f.seek(length);
            b = f.readByte();
        } while (b != 10 && length > 0);
        f.setLength(length + 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Благодаря этому методу можно удалить последнюю строку в файле, не перезаписывая его и, - все ОК. Но, что делать, если эта строка возникает где-то в середине файла?

Comment: Думаю надо переписать запись строк в файл. Сначала преобразовать out в строку нужного вида, так чтобы лишнего переноса не было, а потом просто записать строку в файл

Comment: @Serhii Dikobrazko Ну.... пока не знаю, как это реализовать... Ведь вид строки задается с классе модели, в переопределенном методе toString() и еще, в моем случае в том методе, который сохраняет объект в файл и в Json (там работает BufferedWriter и FileWriter)... Но, я попробую, спасибо!

Comment: @ Roman C Нет, все же не дубликат... Как удалять пустые строки с конца файла - я решил. Здесь вопрос касается того, - как удалить такие же строки, возникающие в середине (в произвольном месте файла).